# gitlab-ci optimisation with docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a very basic asp.net core mvc web application.

I have installed a gitlab-ci server and i have pushed my source and project files to a repository.

I have created this .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:latest

stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
 stage: build
 script:
   - dotnet restore
   - dotnet build

test:
 stage: test
 script:
   - dotnet test Tests
```

I have setup a docker runner on gitlab server.

When i push something with git, the stages build and test jobs starts in the gitlab-ci pileline.

Everything seems to work fine.

I really want to understand everything.

Here are my questions:

First, i can see something like this in the job console:

```
Pulling docker image microsoft/dotnet:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:xxxxxx for microsoft/dotnet:latest ...
Running on runner-xxxxxx-concurrent-0 via myserver...
....
Fetching changes...
....
HEAD is now at xxxxxx test
Checking out xxxxxx as mybranch...
...
$ dotnet test Tests
```

The runner is first creating a docker container. At the end we can see the dotnet command which launch the tests. 
But between, we can see the job is fetching source files from my repository. This is logic because the container need the source files.
But, as you can see, there is nothing in my .gitlab-ci.yml which says to download the source files. This seems to be magic ? But i hate magic in computing !
How the runner can know which source files to download, in which directory ?

Second question: 2 jobs are created in the pipeline: One for building and the second for testing. There are no optimisation, the second container need to re-run the build operations. Is there a way to do this in a single docker container (in order to optimize).

Third, and last question: The jobs are successfully runned but i can see 2 containers entry when i type this command:

```
docker ps -a
```

I can see "Exited (0) 11 hours ago ". Why those containers are not deleted automatically ? If i run hundred of tests, my runner computer will be out of space and memory !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

> How the runner can know which source files to download, in which directory ?

I think looking into gitlab documentation will answer this question:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#git-strategy
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#git-checkout
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#custom-build-directories

Question 2:

> Why those containers are not deleted automatically ? If i run hundred of tests, my runner computer will be out of space and memory !

Sorry for being direct, but little googling might've answered your questions: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2151

Answer from gitlab developer Nikola Kovacs:

> This is working as expected. The cache container has to remain after the build so that the next build can use the cache.
>   Removing it after a build would defeat its purpose.
>
> You can use this to automate the cleanup: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner-docker-cleanup

Comment: I do not understand something You say the cache container will remain but i have added a touch command in build job, which create an empty file. I can see this file is not there in test job...

Comment: I think this is question to be asked on gitlab community. Same container cannot be used in different stages or jobs, mainly because they could be executed on different runners and/or in parallel, therefore this kind of cache cannot be done. I think the cache Nikola is referring is https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#the-builds-and-cache-storage